# Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix ///home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc: connect: permission denied

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc

I have created a shell script on a ubuntu server X with geth Node installed,to insert data in a smart contract in testnet blockchain. Further I am executing the shell script from a PHP file insertscript.php created on the same server X by using shell_exec command. When I call the PHP script  from the command prompt , it gets successfully executed and data gets inserted in the blockchain . But when I call the php script from another server by using cURL or open it in the browser, I will see the error :

**Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix ///home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc: connect: permission denied**

My shell script looks something like:-

```
#!/bin/sh
ATTACHPARAMETER="ipc:///home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc"
INCIDENTUUID=${1:-"photo-55697b7f4a550511448499999999"}
USERUUID=${2:-"null"}
TIMESTAMP=$3
STATUS=$4

echo $INCIDENTUUID
echo $USERUUID
echo $TIMESTAMP
echo $STATUS

geth attach $ATTACHPARAMETER << EOF

var abi = [abi definition];
var address = "addressofContract";
var mycontract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
eth.defaultAddress = eth.accounts[0];
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0],'test');

mycontract.createIncident('$INCIDENTUUID','$USERUUID',$TIMESTAMP,$STATUS,{from:eth.accounts[0],gas:1400000});
console.log("Inserted");


EOF
```

Could you help in finding the cause of this error and also in finding a solution to the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your `geth` binary runs under one user_id, but the webserver runs under another user_id (probably `nobody`,`www` ,or etc)

You have to make the geth.ipc file readable and writable to your webserver, either by group access or by using the same user_id on both processes (the webserver and geth)

Also, note that you can not share `geth` access via IPC (Inter Process Communication) between 2 computers, the IPC works only inside a single computer because it is a kernel-level implementation of data sharing.

Comment: Hi Nulik...thanks for your response....In my code I changed geth attach $ATTACHPARAMETER << EOF to  sudo geth attach $ATTACHPARAMETER << EOF and the Fatal error cannot be seen but the data is still not being inserted. Do you suggest to use rpc instead of ipc?

Comment: I changed to rpc from ipc and the code worked...thanks

Comment: I have the same error, but even when my .ipc file has 777 permissions I am seeing the "permission denied" issue

Comment: @BarneyChambers this in fact occurs if you use virtualization like snap and a file inaccessible to snap app (snap has unofficial very old geth as of current date); theoretically apparmor can also cause that...

Comment: @BarneyChambers For example: `# cat /var/log/kern.log | grep ethereum | tail -1` `Feb 27 14:30:12 pc1 kernel: [173119.964487] audit: type=1400 audit(1614407412.004:204): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="snap.geth.geth" name="/media/user/hdd5/home_user_dot_ethereum/geth/LOCK" pid=87400 comm="geth" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000`

Comment: `mknod` is a filesystem operation, most likely you have some security policy configured by the admin like SELinux or sort of. Do an `strace` and check what paths are blocked for access